# Is InjectUnsetProperties broken on Android (Mono)?

Tags: android, autofac

I'm trying to use the InjectUnsetProperties extension method (on an IContainer obtained from ContainerBuilder.Build) on an Android project (which uses Mono). This results in a TargetInvocationException with the following stack:

```
at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) [0x00082] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:392 
at Autofac.Core.DefaultPropertySelector.InjectProperty (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo, System.Object instance) [0x00031] in <a9f7a03a38f6492fb945f978e615643a>:0
```

In my case, I'm trying to inject properties of an Activity instance. The InnerException is a NoSuchMethodError exception with the message:

> no method with name='getContentTransitionManager' signature='()Landroid/transition/TransitionManager;' in class Landroid/app/Activity;

ContentTransitionManager is a virtual property of the Activity class with a public getter and a public setter.

Also worth mentioning, the InjectProperties extension method works fine in this case.

After searching through the autofac documentation and doing a general web search, I haven't found any reason this shouldn't work, but wanted to check whether I'm missing something. Should I expect InjectUnsetProperties to work in this case?

Comment: Sounds like a potential Mono bug. Have you searched their forums and bug database?

Comment: Yes, I've searched the forum on autofac.org and also the issues list on the Autofac GitHub page, and have not found any references to this problem.

Comment: I meant did you search the MONO forums or bug database. This only happens on Mono and Autofac uses Portable Class Library tech (in 3.5.x) or standard .NET multi-targeting (in 4.x) so if it's not working, chances are it's a Mono problem. You probably won't find Mono specific issues in the Autofac discussions.